# Why there are no headers in java?

Tags: java, preprocessor-directive

I understand there are number of problems we have with this during compilation in previous languages

like for example  ::

```
#define PI_PLUS_ONE (3.14 + 1)
x = PI_PLUS_ONE * 5; // a line of code
```

if i don't use parenthesis i will be getting different result than the expected output.
So what i want to say is if we understand it very well we can take it advantages one of it is type neutral in defining constants.

What Are the reasons(main) behind the restriction of this headers in java?

Thanks in Advance for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763692/java-preprocess-phase

Comment: In Java, there are no `#define` headers. If you want to define anything by a name, create a constant: a public static final variable. Java supports preprocessing of code, but not like that of C.

Comment: Questions like these would need to be posed to James Gosling or one of the other early developers of Java, else we'd just be guessing as to what they might have been thinking. Voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is pre-processing in Java, just not the type you describe. Consider Hibernate or the Proxy/Decorator patterns that are available in Java by bytecode instrumentation, etc. This is the pre-processing, adapted for the enterprise.

Comment: I would rather call this post-processing...